# angular-fullstack PUT will not update in backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to run a PUT updating the status of an issue from "unresolved" to "resolved". However, I keep getting TypeError: `$scope.details.$update();` is not a function.

I am using the angular-fullstack yeoman generator.

I have tried following different guides [here](http://tylerhenkel.com/build-an-angular-todo-app-with-a-node-backend/) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

here is my code:

update function in the API

```
 export function update(req, res) {
   if (req.body._id) {
     delete req.body._id;
   }
   WCS.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
     .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
     .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
     .then(respondWithResult(res))
     .catch(handleError(res));
 }
```

functions in my controller to retrieve and manipulate the data.

```
// Search
  $scope.theId = '';

  $scope.details = {};

// Pull function
  $scope.getVOC = function () {
    if ($scope.theId.length === 24) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/WCS/' + $scope.theId)
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.details = data;
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please use an existing ID.');
    }
  };

  // Put function
  $scope.updateVOC = function () {
      $scope.details.$update();
  };
```

And my html:

```
  <form >
    <input ng-model='theId' type='text'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn" ng-click="getVOC()">Search</button>
    <button type="submit" class='btn' ng-click='updateVOC()' name="button">Update</button>
  </form>

<div>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<h4>Customer Information</h4>
<tr>
  <td class="col-sm-2">Name:</td>
  <td>{{details.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td>{{details.email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Phone:</td>
  <td>{{details.phone}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company:</td>
  <td>{{details.company}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Status:</td>
 <td>
   <select class='form-control col-sm-2' ng-model="details.resolutionStatus">
     <option>resolved</option>
     <option>unresolved</option>
   </select>
     </td>
</tr>
```

When I select the resolved option and click on the updateVOC function it shows on the scope that the resolution status is now 'resolved', but that change does not update the database. I need it to save in the database.

Comment: I don't see where `$scope.details.$update()` is defined in the source you've provided. I just see that you're calling it. Are you sure that its defined?

Comment: @peteb, how would I go about defining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ng-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) doesn't have an $update, but you can make a custom PUT request yourself